# IOS IAP or PayPal for Auto-Renewable Subscription?

Tags: ios, paypal, in-app-purchase

I have a question Is Apple OK with the use of PayPal API in an iOS App, for Subscribe classes(Real World Service) or I have to use IAP? I'm confused what to use?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly is "Real World Service"

Comment: If  he service is consumed in the app (like music) then IAP. If the service is something like a gym membership, then not IAP.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks... it is music class membership ? It is ok? I'm only showing different type of classes name like basic,standard etc..

Comment: Definitely not IAP then.

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11.. You clear my confusion.